# Complex curved integral: $\int_{\gamma(t)}\frac{1}{z+2}dz$, with: $\gamma(t)=\cos(3t)+i5\sin(5t)$ where $t\in [-\pi,\pi]$.

Tags: residue-calculus, complex-integration, curves

I am stuck computing the following complex integral: 
$$\int_{\gamma(t)}\frac{1}{z+2}dz$$
with: $\gamma(t)=\cos(3t)+i5\sin(5t)$ where $t\in [-\pi,\pi]$.

What is the easiest way? How do you represent the curve?

The result is "$0$" but I do not know how it is done.

Would appreciate if somebody could explain it to me.

Comment: $-2 < \cos\left(\,3t\,\right)$. So,$\ldots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. This is a [Lissajous curve](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LissajousCurve.html). Does this "twisted" closed curve (see [picture](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric%20plot%20(cos(3t),%205sin(5t))%20in%20%5B-pi..pi%5D)) go around  the pole $z=-2$? Note that $|\mbox{Re}(\gamma(t))|=|\cos(3t)|\leq 1$ and then use the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
Perhaps it is a curve of Lissajous; But because it is centered in the pole, and if I apply the residue theorem I do not get 2$\pi$i?
However how do I draw the curve?

Comment: @Semir The curve is not centered at the pole $z=-2$. In this case you are lucky and there is no need to draw the curve. I edited my answer with a linked picture.

Comment: Why am I lucky? How do I solve it without knowing how the curve is made?

Comment: @Semir Did you follow my hint about $|\mbox{Re}(\gamma(t))|\leq 1$?

Comment: I do not know that hypothesis, but if I apply the residue theorem I have $2\pi*i * (Res (-2)) $ where Res (-2) is 1 and the result is $2\pi*i \neq 0$

Comment: @Semir Read carefully the link I gave you about Residue Theorem. You should consider the residue at the poles which are INSIDE the closed curve.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see it, thank you.
So if I do not know how the curve is made, how do I know if the pole is inside the curve?

Comment: @Semir The absolute value of the real component of the curve is bounded by $1$ so it can't go around $z=-2$ (whose real component has magnitude $2>1$).

Comment: Ok, I understand, thank you very much;